# hide video.js speaker icon in browser

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I have a muted video (video.js) as background on my site. The browser tab shows an speaker icon next to page title. How can I  prevent to display this icon? My video is only a background, it don't have any sound. I don't know if the video editor clear or not the audio soundtrack, but the fact is that the video is muted.

Here my embed code:

```
<!-- Video.js Player -->
<video id="videoBanner2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin hidden-xs" width="100%" data-setup='{ "autoplay": true, "loop":true, "preload":true, "controls":false , "muted":true, "poster": "https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/.jpg" }'>
 <source src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/.mp4" type='video/mp4' />     
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that 
 <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
<script>
//pa que arranque en safari & chrome
  var $video = $('#videoBanner2');
  $video.on('canplaythrough', function() {
     this.play();
  });
</script>
<!-- /Video.js Player -->
```

Answer (score 0):

add a css rule

```
.video-js .vjs-mute-control, .video-js .vjs-volume-menu-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem, perhaps adding this code would help. On my site the speaker icon already gone.

```
<script>
   var vid = document.getElementById("videoBanner2");
   vid.muted = true;
</script>
```